# Specific folder and no thumbnail generation for media_sideload_image

Tags: media

I am using media_sideload_image function in WordPress to upload images automatically from another location on the web.

I want to add two more pieces of functionality.

1. Add these images to a particular folder in my system, which I will specify once within the code.
2. No thumbnails should be generated for these images, just import the image and put it in the folder, and attach to the post.

How can I achieve points 1 and 2? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad 1) Take a look at [`wp_upload_dir`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir).

Ad 2) Try `remove_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`

Comment: I implemented your suggestion: [link]http://pastebin.com/azqhHnGU

However the images are not getting attached to my posts (using media_sideload_image function). Within the post when I check the attached image, the url is incorrectly pointing to /uploads/imagefile.jpg instead of /uploads/wp-site-gallery/imagefile.jpg.

Any idea for a fix?

Comment: deleted the other post, if you could provide more help on this problem that would be great, thanks.